# thinkpython2 right justify column 70 meaning

Tags: python, justify

thinkpython2[thinkpython2 link](http://greenteapress.com/thinkpython2/thinkpython2.pdf) has exercise 3.1 that specifies a function right_justify should print a string s with the last letter of the string in column 70.

The exact question is:
Exercise 3.1. Write a function named right_justify that takes a string named s as a parameter and prints the string with enough leading spaces so that the last letter of the string is in column 70 of the display.

There is also a hint provided:
Hint: Use string concatenation and repetition. Also, Python provides a built-in function called len that returns the length of a string, so the value of len('monty') is 5.

Is there a standard for determining so-called column locations? How would you write the code??

Example Code:

```
>>>right_justify('monty')
                                                                       monty
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code, don't link to it.

Comment: All the code provided is included here. The link is just in case someone wants to see the underlying .pdf for more context.

Comment: Are you asking for the definition of "right justify"?

Comment: Also I figured thinkpython2e (e.g. the new How to Think Like a Computer Scientist) would be so well known folks would be ready to open the .pdf from prior experience learning from it.

Comment: Asking for what the question means by "column 70". Actually hold on, I'll edit to post the entire question

Comment: Column 70 means that it is the 70th character in the line.

Comment: right_justify is not a standard library function of python, kindly mention which module did u import, and what exact details you are looking for?

Comment: @nandal, Daniel is being asked to implement that function. He is asking for help understanding part of the specification.

Comment: P.S. If anyone finds this question even remotely original and useful, please hook me up with a +1 :). Been trying to score one of those for a while.

Comment: There is the `str.rjust` method, but I guess you aren't allowed to use that for this exercise. Although you could use it during development to test that your code does the same thing as that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine what "column" the last letter of a string is in is the same as its length.

From the pdf:
"Hint: Use string concatenation and repetition. Also, Python provides a built-in function called len that returns the length of a string, so the value of len('monty') is 5."

Answer (score 1):

I would have done it this way, hope this helps

```
def right_justify(s, total_length = 70):
    return ' ' * (total_length - len(s)) + s
right_justify('Monty')
```